# Dart Unit Tests - Await Results of an Async Function in Class Constructor

Tags: unit-testing, dart, async-await

I have a `FooViewModel` that is supposed to check Cloud Firestore for a `mainFoo` upon initialization, and set a `mainFoo` property to this value if one is found.

Since it's looking at cloud Firestore, it's an asynchronous function.

The view is supposed to show an empty value view if no `mainFoo` exists, and a view showing the `mainFoo` if one does exist.

This works fine in practice, but where I'm struggling is my unit testing.

I want to test that this method is called when the viewModel is initialized, and that it does set the `mainFoo` if one does exist. But setting my result to `mainFoo` seems to happen before `loadMainFoo` has completed, and result still ends up as null.

Here's the basics of what's in the class:

```
class FooViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  // MARK
  // Properties
  Foo? mainFoo;

  FooViewModel() {
    loadMainFoo();
  }

  /// Returns the mainFoo if there is one.
  Future<Foo>? loadMainFoo() async {
      // Code in here to load the Foo from Firestone, and sets the mainFoo to the Foo that gets loaded.
  }
}
```

My test sets `sut` to a new instance of `FooViewModel`, which will also trigger `loadMainFoo`. The next line is to set my result to the `mainFoo` property in `sut`.

This is where the issue seems to happen - I know that `loadMainFoo` is being called, but `result` is getting set before `loadMainFoo` has finished, and it still ends up as null.

Is there any way to make sure result doesn't get set until I can be sure `loadMainFoo` has completed?
As far as I know I can't make the constructors asynchronous.

```
      test('Makes sure mainFoo exists after logic performed', () async {
        // ARRANGE
        sut = FooViewModel();

        // ACT
        var result = sut.mainFoo;

        // ASSERT
        expect(result != null, true);
      });
```

Comment: I tried just adding `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0))` right before I set the result, and even with a value of 0 seconds, it seems to fix the issue. This seems like a useful workaround, but I'm still curious if there's a way to specifically await until the constructor has finished.

Comment: Well, the constructor *has* finished. You cannot `await` an `async` method in the constructor, it's not async itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know I can't make the constructors asynchronous.

Correct.  Constructors must return an instance of the constructed class without exception.  Constructors therefore cannot return a `Future`, and therefore if a constructor does any asynchronous work, callers cannot be directly notified when that asynchronous work completes.

If your constructor must do asynchronous work, you instead can:

- Make the constructor private and use a `static` method as a factory method:

  ```dart
  class FooViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
    Foo mainFoo;

    FooViewModel._(this.mainFoo);

    Future<Foo?> loadMainFoo() async =>
        FooViewModel._(await someAsynchronousOperation());
  }
  ```

  This is the most straightforward for callers.  However, this would prevent `FooViewModel` from being `extend`ed.
- Expose the `Future` for asynchronous work as a property on the constructed object:

  ```dart
  class FooViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
    Foo? mainFoo;

    late final Future<void> initialized;

    FooViewModel.() {
      initialized = loadMainFoo();
    }

    Future<Foo?> loadMainFoo() async {
      ...
    }
  }
  ```

  and then callers can do:

  ```dart
  var sut = FooViewModel();
  await sut.initialized;
  ```

  This is more work for callers and therefore is inherently more error-prone.  Also consider combining `initialized` and `mainFoo` by declaring `mainFoo` as a `Future<Foo?>` directly.

(In the above code, I assumed that `loadMainFoo` is meant to have a return type of `Future<Foo?>` insead of `Future<Foo>?`.)